# Add point to path in python api

Tags: python, bezier-curves

Version: Blender **2.81**

Using the Python API, I want to create a default path and then add individual points to it.

The code below does this. Except that it extends both the beginning and the end of the curve.

```
import bpy

# kill everything

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)

# create curve

bpy.ops.curve.primitive_nurbs_path_add(radius=1, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))

# switch to edit mode

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

# add new point for curve

bpy.ops.curve.extrude_move(CURVE_OT_extrude={"mode":'TRANSLATION'}, 
    TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 2, 0)}
    )
```

In the viewpoint, I can extend the END of the curve by toggling edit mode, and then doing this: double-clicking the last point, and pressing E.

I can't figure out how to use python to select this last point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (I am on Blender 2.81a):

```
import bpy

# kill everything
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)

# create curve
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_nurbs_path_add(radius=1, enter_editmode=False)
obj = bpy.context.object

# De-select all points
for pn in obj.data.splines[0].points:
    pn.select = False

# Select the last point
pn = obj.data.splines[0].points
end_point_idx = (len(obj.data.splines[0].points) - 1)
pn[end_point_idx].select = True

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') # Edit mode

bpy.ops.curve.extrude_move(CURVE_OT_extrude={"mode":'TRANSLATION'},
TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 2, 0)})

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT') # Object mode
```

(Make sure you are in object mode when you run it)